# How to use one instance of MediaPlayer for several fragments

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-mediaplayer

I am creating a soundboard app. The app will feature different "pages" (fragments within viewpager) that the user can switch between. Each fragment has a number of ImageButtons that, when clicked on, will play a certain sound.

In each of my fragment classes I put the following code in its OnCreateView method like the following example below.

```
public static class FragmentPage1 extends Fragment {

    int selectedSoundId;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page1, container, false);


        final MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
        final Resources res = getResources();

        final int[] buttonIds = { R.id.btn1, R.id.btn2, R.id.btn3, R.id.btn4, R.id.btn5, R.id.btn6, R.id.btn7, R.id.btn8, R.id.btn9 };
        final int[] soundIds = { R.raw.sound1, R.raw.sound2, R.raw.sound3, R.raw.sound4, R.raw.sound5, R.raw.sound6, R.raw.sound7, R.raw.sound8, R.raw.sound9 };

        View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for (int i = 0; i < buttonIds.length; i++) {
                    if (v.getId() == buttonIds[i]) {
                        selectedSoundId = soundIds[i];
                        AssetFileDescriptor afd = res.openRawResourceFd(soundIds[i]);
                        player.reset();
                        try {
                            player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        try {
                            player.prepare();
                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        player.start();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < buttonIds.length; i++) {
            ImageButton soundButton = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(buttonIds[i]);
            registerForContextMenu(soundButton);
            soundButton.setOnClickListener(listener);
        }
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

I have twelve different fragments that have a set of nine buttons on each. So as you can see I have twelve instances of this MediaPlayer code (one in each fragment). I've been trying to find a way to simplify this but I have so far come up with nothing.

How can I edit my code to make it so that I only have to use one instance of this MediaPlayer code?

Comment: you can make static instance in Application calss and use it from there

Comment: Better (in some people's minds, including my own) than a singleton would be to use a `Service` and put the `MediaPlayer` there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use singleton pattern, like this:

```
public class MediaPlayerSingleton extends MediaPlayer{
    private static MediaPlayerSingleton mediaPlayerSingleton;

    private MediaPlayerSingleton() {}

    public static MediaPlayerSingleton getInstance() {
        synchronized (mediaPlayerSingleton)  { // if you'll be using it in moe then one thread
            if(mediaPlayerSingleton == null)
                mediaPlayerSingleton = new MediaPlayerSingleton();
        }

        return mediaPlayerSingleton;
    }

}
```

And then use your player anywhere you want like this:

```
MediaPlayerSingleton mediaPlayer = MediaPlayerSingleton.getInstance();
    mediaPlayer.reset(); // some call
```

Comment: Oh my gosh! You just solved my biggest problem in my soundboard app!!! I'd upvote your answer a thousand times if I could. Thank you!